# SQL Server : implicit calculation of precision/scale for datetime scalar

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm working with an application that ( for whatever reason... ) is unable to pass datetime stamps into its SQL Server database. Where the application needs a datetime stamp, it will push the server datetime in string format into a string datapoint. For many situations, it is perfectly adequate to convert via `case isdate(ApplicationDatetimestamp) when 1 then convert( datetime, ApplicationDatetimestamp ) end`

**However**:

This is complicated by the fact that many (far too many...) users have been given admin access in the application and are permitted to bypass the standard input methods. Sometimes this is a *very bad* problem ( expect `'2015-11-17 20:32:09.340'`, get `'Tuesdya at ten thirty'` ), sometimes it's a marginally *less bad* problem, ( expect `'2015-11-17 20:32:09.340'`, get `'11/17/2015'` ).

I've been tasked with calculating KPI's from fields of this type. I've largely given up on those fields where implicit conversion does not work ( *very bad* problem examples ), but I'm having some difficulty discarding instances where implicit conversion succeeds but is incorrect due to scale truncation ( the *less bad* problem issue ).

**Example**

I've been asked to show the time difference from input to a due date ( open of business the next day ). I take the user input and calculate `datediff()` to the sanitized input, right? **Wrong**

```
declare
    @GoodInput varchar( 100 ) = '2015-11-17 20:32:09.340',
    @LessBadInput varchar( 100 ) = '11/17/2015',
    @VeryBadInput varchar( 100 ) = 'Tuesdya at ten thirty';

declare 
    @DueBy datetime = '2015-11-18 08:31:00.00',
    @GoodDatetime datetime = convert( datetime,@GoodInput ),
    @LessbadDatetime datetime = case isdate( @LessBadInput ) when 1 then convert( datetime, @LessBadInput ) end,
    @VeryBadDatetime datetime = case isdate( @VeryBadInput ) when 1 then convert( datetime, @VeryBadInput ) end;

select
    GoodInput =     datediff( hour, @GoodDatetime, @DueBy ),
    LessBadInput =  datediff( hour, @LessBadDatetime, @DueBy ),
    VeryBadInput =  datediff( hour, @VeryBadDatetime, @DueBy );
```

returns...

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| GoodInput | LessBadInput | VeryBadInput |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|        12 |           32 | NULL         |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

For the purposes of calculating a business metric, it's better to have no input than partial input... The user who put in the partial date has now tripled the calculated metric - arguably a much worse result than that of the user who put in the misspelled `Tuesdya`.

**Question**:

Is there a preferred method to calculate implicit scale of SQL Server datetime scalar?

If I were able to - in an interim step - determine that the row contains no specificity past the `DAY` level, I could exclude the row from calculation.

The methods I've explored thus far are:

**1: the obvious string manipulation**

Using the below method

```
with StrParse ( Id, Name, Value, StrValue )  as
(
    select 1, 'Good', @GoodDatetime, convert( varchar, @GoodDatetime, 126 )
    union select 2, 'LessBad', @LessBadDatetime, convert( varchar, @LessBadDatetime, 126 )
    union select 3, 'VeryBad', @VeryBadDatetime, convert( varchar, @VeryBadDatetime, 126 )
)
select
    Id,
    rStr =  reverse( StrValue ),
    fNum =  patindex( '%[1-9]%', reverse( StrValue ) ), -- find 
    Value
from StrParse
```

we return

```
+----+-------------------------+------+-------------------------+
| Id |          rStr           | fNum |          Value          |
+----+-------------------------+------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 043.90:23:02T71-11-5102 | 2    | 2015-11-17 20:32:09.340 |
|  2 | 00:00:00T71-11-5102     | 10   | 2015-11-17 00:00:00.000 |
|  3 | NULL                    | NULL | NULL                    |
+----+-------------------------+------+-------------------------+
```

Using this, we'd simply discard anything with an `fNum` < 8 when we want "hours" scale as the minimum allowed input exactness.

However, the string manipulation method ( as currently listed ) seems inelegant. The implicit datetime conversion to string [truncates millisecond scale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) when not present, which provides a different `fNum` scale interpretation ( `fNum` of 10 for Id=2 is the same precision as an `fNum` of 14 for Id=1 ). Obviously, this could be corrected with more string manipulation, but then I'm running down a rabbit hole I never meant to when I just wanted to determine the scale of a datetime scalar...

```
043.90:23:02T71-11-5102
+-------+-------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| digit | place |          Scale           | SecondPartPower |
+-------+-------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| 0     |     1 | millisecond              | -3              |
| 4     |     2 | millisecond ( tens )     | -2              |
| 3     |     3 | millisecond ( hundreds ) | -1              |
| .     |     4 | "."                      | --              |
| 9     |     5 | Seconds ( ones )         | 0               |
| 0     |     6 | Seconds ( tens )         | 1               |
| :     |     7 | ":"                      | --              |
| 2     |     8 | Minutes ( ones )         | 10^1 * 6        |
| 3     |     9 | Minutes ( tens )         | 10^2 * 6        |
| :     |    10 | ":"                      | --              |
| 0     |    11 | Hours ( ones )           | 10^1 * 360      |
| 2     |    12 | Hours ( tens )           | 10^2 * 360      |
| T     |    13 | "T"                      | --              |
| 7     |    14 | day                      |                 |
+-------+-------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

**2: Conversion to numeric**

The immediate concerns become apparent with the below query

```
declare
    @Today date = getdate(),
    @TodayDt datetime = getdate();
declare
    @TenOclock datetime = convert( datetime, @Today ) + convert( time, '10:00:00.0' ),
    @TenOhOne datetime = convert( datetime, @Today ) + convert( time, '10:01:00.0' );

select 
    Today =         @Today,
    TodayLong =     convert( datetime, @Today ),
    TodayDt =       @TodayDt,
    TenOclock =     @TenOclock,
    TenOhOne =      @TenOhOne;

select 
    --Today =       convert( float, @Today ), -- Explicit conversion from data type date to float is not allowed.
    TodayLong =     convert( float, convert( datetime, @Today ) ),
    TodayDt =       convert( float, @TodayDt ),
    TenOclock =     convert( float, @TenOclock ),
    TenOhOne =      convert( float, @TenOhOne );
```

returns

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| TodayLong |     TodayDt      |    TenOclock     |     TenOhOne     |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|     42323 | 42323.9012709877 | 42323.4166666667 | 42323.4173611111 |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Our nice and even `@TenOclock` becomes the rounding mess `42323.4166666667` instead of a nice, decimal place stop. I'm not sure how I would even begin to interpret the rounded fractions without the ( once again ) string manipulation.

**So... is there a more elegant method?**

Obviously, when this is needed, it's nice to convert to a UDF. but I'd really like to have a METHOD that works before trying to compartmentalize and standardize instances where I need this executed.